# C# losing events

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I've got an application which know how to load an assembly and create instance of class from that assembly.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly_name);

foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISimModuleInterface)))
    {
         current_loaded_modules[module_name] = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as simulator2k14.ISimModuleInterface;
         current_loaded_modules[module_name].OnModuleDeiniting += new simulator2k14.OnDeinitingDelegate(current_loaded_module_OnModuleDeiniting);
         current_loaded_modules[module_name].OnModuleIniting += new OnInitingDelegate(mainsim_OnModuleIniting);
         current_loaded_modules[module_name].OnModuleExecuteCommand += new OnExecudeCommandDelegate(mainsim_OnModuleExecuteCommand);

         break;
     }
}
```

Then inside the module initing i'm calling SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle() to pass it in some other function which is working with hardware and genetrating Events. Everything goes okay until i'm starting only one instance of class from one assembly. When i'm loading second instance of class from single assembly to it's looks like it overwrite event for the first instance and all events from driver goes only to second instance.

If i just loading two instances of main application and then loading in each of them only one instances of class from assembly everything goes okay.

How i can solve my problem with two instances of class from one assembly?

Comment: It seems like you're overwriting current_loaded_modules[module_name] every time

Comment: no, module_name is unique for each instance

Comment: @qmor So you're saying from all the types in your assembly 0 or 1 do implement ISimModuleInterface? Otherwise you will enter the if clause more than once and what BlackBear described will happen

Comment: fyi this might throw if the class is abstract or another interface.

Comment: Is this "driver" even capable of supporting multiple clients that each use their own wait handle?  It is not that common and trivially explains your problem.

Comment: assembly contains only one class which implements ISimModuleInterface. It's real non abstract class

Comment: i think driver is supporting for multiple client waiting events, because if i'm starting two applications separately everything is okay. Maybe i need to use own AppDomain for each instance of assembly?